# Android sqlite db.query leads to CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am trying to select certain rows from my database, but since I kept getting index out of bound I decided to remove the `WHERE` part for now and just get all of the data.
I have used the android tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#DbHelper , in order to create this method. But when I am trying to get values from the query I am getting CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException.

My Code:

```
String getSite() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            //get all data for now
    Cursor c = db.query(
        TABLE_NAME,  // The table to query
        null,                               // The columns to return
        null,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
        null,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
        null,                                     // don't group the rows
        null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
        null                                 // don't sort
        );
    c.moveToFirst();
        String test= c.getString(0); 
    c.close();
    return test;}
}
```

The Error:
    `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 6`

when I checked for c.count() I got 6, so I am not sure why I am referring to an index that might out of bound

Thank you

Comment: While you should always check the return value of `moveToFirst()`, this code shouldn't throw this exception. Are you sure this is where the error occurs?

Comment: Agree with @Sam - I can't see anything wrong with that code either.

Comment: Yes I am positive. Adding this to my code solves the issue, but I am not sure why
`if(c.moveToFirst()){do{`
 `System.out.println(c.getString(0));`
   `} while (c.moveToNext());`
    `}`

Comment: Please post all of the Logcat errors.

Comment: can you debug the cursor on the `String test = c.getString(0);` line and tell us what index c is at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cursor is empty if it didn't move.

try

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    String test= c.getString(0);
    // or String test= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("column_name")); 
}
```