# error in sqlite android when trying to access database

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am trying to use sqlite database on android.Below is my SQL helper class which i am using to access sqlite database.

```
public class SQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
static final String TABLE_NAME = "itemDetail";
static final String ID  ="id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT";
static final String ITEM = "item";
static final String QUANTITY = "quantity";
static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+SQLHelper.TABLE_NAME+"( " + ID +" , "+SQLHelper.ITEM+" TEXT "+" , "+SQLHelper.QUANTITY+" INTEGER"+" )";
static final String DB_NAME = "mydb";

public SQLHelper(Context context, int version) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    arg0.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    arg0.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);

    // create fresh books table
    this.onCreate(arg0);
}



public long add(String item , String q){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ITEM, item);
    values.put(QUANTITY , q);
    long newr = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,  "null", values);

    db.close();
    return newr;
}
public Cursor read(){
    Cursor cc;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.d("report","ok");
    cc=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM itemDetail", null);
    Log.d("report","ok2");
    db.close();
    //cc.moveToFirst();
    Log.d("good",cc.getString(1));
    return cc;

}
```

}

when ever i use cc (Cursor object) to access rows returned by query command my program stops. I think that rawQuery is not returning any row. please help.thanks

logcat

```
 01-13 22:12:37.921: E/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by:        android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 23
 01-13 22:12:37.921: E/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
 01-13 22:12:37.921: E/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
 01-13 22:12:37.921: E/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
  01-13 22:12:37.921: E/AndroidRuntime(341):    at it.is.appone.SQLHelper.read(SQLHelper.java:63)
 01-13 22:12:37.921: E/AndroidRuntime(341):     at it.is.appone.Report.show(Report.java:36)
  01-13 22:12:37.921: E/AndroidRuntime(341):    ... 14 more
```

below is the function in an activity class from which i am trying to access database.

```
public void show(View view){
    //Toast.makeText(this, "in show", 5000).show();
    SQLHelper myh = new SQLHelper(this,dbversion);
    SQLiteCursor cc=(SQLiteCursor) myh.read();
    //readDB();

    Log.d("Report5"," in report");
    String text = new String();
    try{
    if(cc != null){
       cc.moveToFirst();
       text = cc.getString(1);
    }
    else
    {
        text = "bad";
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), 5000);
    }

    Log.d("report data base", text );

    /*while (!cc.isAfterLast()){
        String t = cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SQLHelper.ITEM));
        text = text +  t;
    }*/
    //Toast.makeText(this, "everthing ok", 5000).show();

}
```

Comment: 1. Post the exception stacktrace from logcat. 2. Post the code where that occurs. 3. Only close() the database when you're done using it.

Comment: The code snippet and stacktrace do not agree. The exception suggests you forgot to move the cursor to a valid row.

Comment: how can i move cursor to the valid row? thanks for replying

Comment: using one of the `moveTo...()` methods - since you have `moveToFirst()` there you're already doing it and that's why the code doesn't agree with the error. Also should check whether the move succeeds (if it didn't, there's a different exception though).

Comment: @user3190959 `if(moveToFirst())` .This method will return false if the cursor is empty.

Comment: tried everthing . even cc.getCount() is giving error.

Comment: @user3190959 looks like cursor is empty.

Answer (score 0):

please check always cursor that it should not be null , for this purpose  use following code...

```
if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
```

you closed

```
db.close();
```

before getting cursor as well.close the db after closing the cursor

please send more information regarding logcat and exact problem

Comment: cursor cannot be null. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])

Comment: yes asolutely correct and we should check it if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst(); for consistency and error handling

Comment: wrong. see the docs. cursor will not be null. you need only `if(cursor.moveToFirst())`. i also made the same mistake but selvin pointed my mistake and i re-checked the docs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910152/android-sqlite-cursoroutofboundsexception/20910179#20910179

Comment: what i have written , is it wrong??please guide me and please correct it. and for the user it will be better if you will post an answer with correct answer :)